# match part of a url

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get all matches for any url's that have `index.php?route=forum/` in them

Example urls to filter are:

http://test.codetrove.com/index.php?route=forum/forum

http://test.codetrove.com/index.php?route=forum/forum_category&forum_path=2

So i need the match to be true if it contains `index.php?route=forum/` the http and domain can be anything like http or https or any domain.

Any idea's?

Comment: is there a reason for not simply checking if $_GET['route'] starts with `forum` ?

Comment: if (strpos($url, "index.php?route=forum/") !== false) //if found == true

Comment: how about preg_match()??

Comment: strpos() is much faster than preg_match(). http://lzone.de/articles/php-string-search.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a baseball bat to bludgeon a spider, take a look at strpos().

```
$string = "index.php?route=forum/";
if (strpos($url, $string) !== false) {
    //we have a match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex :

```
/index\.php\?route=forum\/.*/
```

Or with the $_GET variable

```
if(preg_match('/forum\/.*/', $_GET['route'])) {
    echo 'yahoo';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the php `strpos` function documented [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$IsMatch = strpos ( $url , "index.php?route=forum/");
```

Comment: Surround it with backtics (`) on both sides.